# What open-source software can import Yahoo! Pipes pipe definitions?

Tags: gratis, open-source, rss

Due to Yahoo! [closing](http://pipes.yqlblog.net/post/120705592639/pipes-end-of-life-announcement) its amazing Pipes service on August 31, 2015, one is looking for offline RSS processing engines that can import the logic of a Yahoo pipe from a file and actually replicate the result generating an RSS feed.

Requirements:

- Written in well-known scripting or compilable languages
- As a minimum, working on Unix, but desirable as a cross-platform solution
- Gratis
- Open source
- As small train of dependencies as possible

It would be great to have Pipes' web interface - but not directly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [pipe2py](https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py) you can see it [hosted on Google App Engine](http://pipes-engine.appspot.com).

- Python is definitely a well known language
- It is python so should be cross platform
- Gratis
- Open Source *hosted on github*
- The requirements.txt file is only 13 lines long so I don't think that the dependencies are excessive
- Even handles cases where the original pipe had user prompts.